# Was Anakin ever better than Yoda with the lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In Attack of the Clones, this conversation takes place between Obi-Wan and Anakin:

> OBI-WAN: - If you'd spend as much time working on your saber skills as you do on your wit, young Padawan, you would rival Master Yoda as a swordsman.
>
> ANAKIN: -  I thought I already did.
>
> OBI-WAN: - Only in your mind, my very young apprentice.

Was Anakin better than Master Yoda at lightsaber fighting at that moment? If not, did he - or Darth Vader - ever become better?

Comment: It doesn't seem like anyone can beat Yoda one on one in the canon I've seen so far... which makes it odd that he's waiting for someone else to bring balance to the force.

Comment: Well, I think Rambo is the only single-man who can win a war without team play - but I haven't actually seen Rambo yet

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Rambo vs Chuck Norris

Comment: I'd put my money on 45 year old Vader beating dying old swamp-Yoda.

Comment: @Mark Rogers - "It doesn't seem like anyone can beat Yoda one on one in the canon I've seen so far" - Well, Palpatine at least fought him to a draw.

Comment: @Hypnosifl -  In the movie it seemed like Palpatine was trying to escape the fight with Yoda.  Palpatine seemed at first confident and then later dismayed at Yoda's skills, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Mark Rogers - The fight doesn't move from Palpatine's office to the Senate chamber because Palpatine was trying to escape, but because they were fighting on his podium inside his office and then the elevator mechanism got triggered (maybe just by their weight?) and lifted them into the Senate chamber. They seem about evenly matched in the lightsaber fight, then there's a cut to Obi-Wan and Anakin, then when the film cuts back to Yoda and Palpatine, Palpatine is no longer using his lightsaber but instead uses force lightning and tossing of senate pods...we don't know what happened in between.

Comment: (continued) However, the novelization does suggest Yoda eventually gave up because he realized he didn't have what it took to win, though it's possible this wasn't mainly based on lightsaber skills, the text sort of suggests it was a broader philosophical realization that the Jedi had become mired in the past while the Sith had "become new", and that "the new Sith could not be destroyed with a lightsaber .... how could one win a war against the dark, when war itself had become the dark's own weapon?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Anakin/Vader has never surpassed Yoda's skill in lightsaber combat.

In Attack of the Clones, Anakin lost his arm to Dooku. Dooku would have lost to Yoda if the former did not distract the latter in order to escape. Therefore, Yoda > Dooku > Anakin.

In Revenge of the Sith, Anakin lost to Obi-Wan. Since Yoda is considered one of if not the best swordsman in the Order, I think it is safe to assume that Yoda > Obi-Wan > Anakin.

Anakin went through the following changes in his transition to Vader-hood:

- His potential in the Force is diminished. Palpatine once told Yoda that Anakin "will become more powerful than either of us". After Mustafar, though, Palpatine concluded that Anakin will never reach his full potential.
- Vader's suit inhibited his prior combat style. The Jedi tend to favour more acrobatic styles, but Vader's suit has a lot of bulk and deadweight, slowing Vader down.
- To compensate, Vader changed his style, sacrificing the speed he already lost in favour of power and accuracy. In time, he adapted and honed on those aspects further, as well as improving his physical stamina.

It is still fairly easy for Jedi survivors to evade Vader's attacks, but Vader is still able to keep up enough to press the attack and wear them down - he no longer creates openings like before, but simply waits for one. Having enough speed and agility to evade his attacks is one thing - having enough of those attributes to overcome his defences is another. It is, however, a weakness that Yoda's speed, agility, combat style and skill in the Force is sufficient to exploit. Therefore, if the faster and more agile Anakin couldn't win before, he most certainly couldn't ever do so as Vader now, even in spite of the changes and improvements with age.

You may argue Yoda is older during the Empire, but firstly, age doesn't affect a Jedi much, given the restorative properties of the natural Force. Secondly, what is another 20 years to a 900 year old? Yoda only showed signs of age and impending death after Luke arrived on Dagobah (and probably introduced a foreign bacteria that Yoda wasn't vaccinated against).

The Wookieepedia entries for [Anakin Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker#Lightsaber_abilities) and [Yoda](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda#Powers_and_abilities) describe their combat styles. If you accept Legends information, the Legends sections go into more detail. The Legends section on [Darth Vader's suit](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader's_armor#Lightsaber_combat) also goes into more detail how it affected his style in combat. The Legends history of [lightsaber combat](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_combat/Legends) is an overview that highlighted their styles as well.

Comment: By the time Vader fights in that fashion, Yoda is nearing his death. Do you think Yoda would fare better against Vader when he couldn't even beat R2 in a fight over "the world's worst flashlight"?

Comment: @Axelrod Yoda could raise an X-Wing from the depths of hell at will. I always thought it's obvious on hindsight that that entire scene of being a crazy old hermit is meant to be a test of Luke's worthiness to be trained by him. If he really wanted that flashlight, he would have torn R2 apart if it comes down to it. Don't forget: As late as 2 BBY, in Star Wars Rebels, he was still communing with, guiding and training Jedi telepathically. How many Jedi can manipulate a kyber crystal light years away with the Force?

Comment: I think when it comes to combat when you say A>B and B>C this does not always mean A>C, just like with paper-scissors-rock. But good answer nonetheless!

Comment: @IvoBeckers True, but given a lack of actual info, an extrapolation from what you do have is the best you can do - and extrapolations, by nature, are inaccurate, even if we still use them as if they are reliable indicators.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! `Luke arrived on Dagobah (and probably introduced a foreign bacteria that Yoda wasn't vaccinated against)` - was the bacteria thing ever mentioned or something you've made up?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Never mentioned, but haven't you ever thought Yoda falling ill and dying the moment Luke visits is suspicious? The same thing happened when Europeans colonised the Americas and Australia... ;)

Comment: Probably some virulent strain of midichlorians.  :)

Comment: "and probably introduced a foreign bacteria that Yoda wasn't vaccinated against". Sorry, I love the comment (that Luke introduced a pathogen that killed off Yoda), but I have to point out that you vaccinate against viruses, you can't vaccinate against bacteria . . . sorry

Comment: It might also be worth noting regarding Dooku vs. Yoda, that Dooku had JUST finished fighting off two jedi simultaneously. Yoda by all appearances had just been commanding the battle, which, while important, shouldn't be as physically taxing. And Dooku is not a young man, it's likely he was tired. Whether the end result would have been the same anyway, I'd guess so but who knows.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Sure you can. https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vpd/pneumo/index.html .

Comment: I'm re-reading this answer for years later and got surprised again by the bacteria theory 